# Null user exception in Owin Cookie Authentication in Dotvvm

Tags: dotvvm

When using Cookie Authentication in Dotvvm, I get a Null user exception thrown.

I used the following code in the dotvvm configuration:

```
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Authentication code MUST be in the first line of the Configuration(IAppBuilder app) function and that will get rid of the null user exception:

```
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to also set up the `Provider` property and handle the `OnRedirect`, otherwise the redirects made by OWIN Security library won't be applied correctly.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnApplyRedirect = e => DotvvmAuthenticationHelper.ApplyRedirectResponse(e.OwinContext, e.RedirectUri)
    }
});
```